# How to DumpSave a function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I try to define a function in a module and then to save the function definitions to a file using `DumpSave`. However, reloading the function fails. Here's a minimal example

```
buildf[]:= Module[{res},
    res[x_]:=x^2;
    res
];
f=buildf[];
DumpSave["f.mx", f];
Clear[f];
Get["f.mx"]
```

Now I would expect `f` to be the square function, however it remains undefined after the `Clear` statement. How can I resolve this?

The question is closely related to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142671/caching-of-data-in-mathematica) a few months ago, but the solution there does not help me here.

Any hint appreciated!

**Update**
The `buildf` is reading several data files, transforms them, defines rules based on them and calls Dispatch to make lookup fast. The function returned by `buildf` is then something like an API to the data. I want to avoid calls to `buildf` and rather load a binary dump of the created data function.

The `Save` method seems promising, but it still does not work. I will try to isolate the problem so I can reproduce it here.

**Final Update**
After the comment of @Leonid that uniqueness of local variables is not guaranteed across sessions, I decided to use this "DumpSave caching mechanism" only for plain data structures, not functions depending on other symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a local variable (`res`) from `Module`.  Of course this doesn't work and you end up with a "localized" (renamed) version of `res`.

Try

```
f = buildf[]
?f
```

and you'll get something like `f=res$538`.  This local variable has attribute `Temporary` and can get removed (and thus `f` can stop working) at any minute.

If you `DumpSave` the symbol `f`, its definition as  `f=res$538` will be saved, and it can be reloaded (as you can verify with `?f`).  But this is not very useful.

The question here is: *why are you using this `buildf` function at all?*  What are you trying to achieve?

**EDIT:** As Leonid pointed out below, what I wrote above is not completely correct: the symbols with `DownValue`s returned from `Module` do not seem to get removed, even if they're not referenced.  One might still wonder if this behaviour is consistent between versions and will be the same in the future.

Comment: You said: "This local variable has attribute Temporary and can get removed (and thus f can stop working) at any minute."  Can you show this to be true?  Will *Mathematica* actually garbage-collect something like this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I can't right now, I got it from the docs: "Symbols with attribute Temporary are automatically removed when they are no longer needed."  I'm also interested in the answer, but it's bedtime for me now.  I'll check tomorrow :-)

Comment: Okay.  I think crux is what "no longer needed" means.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Szabolcs As soon as you return a variable from the `Module`, it becomes not garbage - collectable, so no worries about that. But I would not `DumpSave` definitions for such symbols,  or any expression involving them, since their uniqueness is only guaranteed for a single Mathematica session.

Comment: @Leonid Do you know what is the exact function of the attribute `Temporary`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I should have been more precise. Symbols with an Attribute `Temporary` the system is free to collect whenever there are no global references to them. When you return such a symbol to the top level, there is a reference to it in `Out`. If you remove the `Out` history, it will be collected. Likewise, if such symbol is part of another expression which is passed to some other place, it might be referenced from there, in which case it won't be collected until that reference is not removed.

Comment: @Leonid That is exactly what I tried before I commented: I returned a symbol from `Module`, to which I assigned `DownValue` definitions.  Then I did `Clear[Out]`, and checked the "temporary" symbol with `Information`.  The definition still existed.  Can we take this to chat?

Comment: @Szabolcs Would love to, but am a bit short of time right now. Later, may be?

Answer (score 3):

You can see something of what is happening if you use `Save` in place of `DumpSave`.

I get a file that looks like this:

```
f = res$636

Attributes[res$636] = {Temporary}

res$636[x_] := x^2
```

This (`Save` rather than `DumpSave`) actually works, but I suggest that the `Temporary` attribute causes this to be lost, or not saved in the first place, when using `DumpSave`.

---

I must reject my assertion above, as I can manually clear the `Temporary` attribute from the `res$*` symbol, and it still fails to save and load.

Comment: +1 for showing that `(Dump)Save` saves the "dependencies" of the function too (i.e. the definitions of symbols used in the definition of the saved function).

Comment: Indeed `Save` does create a more complete mx file, however in the real use case the reloaded function is not working. I added some more information on the problem in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently much more basic than I first thought.  I rarely use `DumpSave` myself because of the system-dependent binary format created, and I thought it behaved much like `Save`.  However, this does not appear to be the case.

Consider:

```
test[x_] := x^2
f = test;
DumpSave["test.mx", f]
Quit[]
```

Followed by:

```
Get["test.mx"]
Information[f]
Information[test]
```

On my system, no definition for `test` is saved and/or loaded.

Contrast with:

```
test2[x_] := x^2
f2 = test2;
Save["test2.m", f2]
Quit[]
```

Followed by:

```
Get["test2.m"]
Information[f2]
Information[test2]
```

Where the definition for `test2` is correctly saved and loaded.

Comment: Maybe the difference is that `Save` uses `FullDefinition` according to the documentation, and `DumpSave` is not.